# Performance difference between bitwise XOR vs summations seems off

Tags: c++, performance

I recently saw a nice solution to a programming problem. Given 2 lists, find the missing number in one of the lists.

My initial solution was like this:

```
long long missing_2(long long a[], long long b[], long long bsize) {
    long long asum = a[bsize], bsum = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < bsize; i++) {
        asum += a[i];
        bsum += b[i];
    }
    return asum-bsum;
}
```

but someone suggested something like this:

```
long long missing_3(long long a[], long long b[], long long bsize) {
    long long sum = 0 ^ a[bsize];
    for (long long i = 0; i < bsize; i++) {
        sum ^= a[i];
        sum ^= b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

out of curiosity, I timed the 2 solutions thinking that the second one `missing_3` would be faster. I got these results

> missing_2: Time taken: 16.21s
>
> missing_3: Time taken: 23.39s

The lists are generated using a for-loop. List b is filled with ints `0-1000000000` and list a is filled 1-1000000000 with a random number appended at the end (so that it contains 1 different (extra) value.

**Question**
The bitwise version takes 23.39s, the summation version takes 16.21s. Any idea why the bitwise version would be noticeably slower than the summation version? I would have assumed bitwise operations would be faster than addition or at least similar.

Edit:

compiled using `g++` with no extra flag/options.

Edit2:

Tested with flags `-O1` and `-O2`, no noticeable difference.

Edit3:

Here is the driver code:

```
    long long smaller_size = 1000000000;
    
    long long* a = new long long[smaller_size+1];
    long long* b = new long long[smaller_size];

    for(long long i = 0; i < smaller_size; i++){
        a[i] = b[i] = i;
    }
    a[smaller_size] = 1434;
    // std::cout << missing_1(a, b, smaller_size) << std::endl;
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    std::cout << "Start List Test\n";

    std::cout << missing_2(a, b, smaller_size) << std::endl;
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    tStart = clock();
    std::cout << missing_3(a, b, smaller_size) << std::endl;
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Edit 5: Timing section updated (No time change)

```
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    std::cout << "Start List Test\n";
    double time; 

    missing_2(a, b, smaller_size);
    time = (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", time);
    tStart = clock();
    missing_3(a, b, smaller_size);
    time = (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", time);
```

Comment: It's not much slower. Did you compile with optimisations turned on?

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is with a billion but it's clear that with higher values the summation version would start pulling away. With 100 Million it's 26s vs 33s. I didn't change anything with the compiler. That's a good point.

Comment: Someone with rep of over 500 should know by now that anything to do with timing C++ applications should be accompanied by the compiler options they used to build the application.

Comment: *compiled using g++ with no extra flag/options.* -- Then rebuild your program using `-O2` or `-O3` and rerun your tests.

Comment: I don't keep up to date with current ALU implementations, but the xor version looks like it should lose a tick due to pipelining. I.e xor b must wait for the result of xor a.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no noticeable difference with `-O2` or `-O3`. I will add that as an edit to my post. @Peter, neither do I but if that's true that would make sense, cool thought!

Comment: My understanding is an XOR operation is faster then an ADD or subtract operation.  However, we are talking in units of nanoseconds (or faster).  IMHO, unless you have 1e+09 operations (or more), the difference between using XOR or add/subtract is insignificant.  The speed you gain will be wasted in other parts of the program or by the operating system in swapping out your program.

Comment: @huddie96  Another thing you're missing -- *how* are you timing these tests?  I see no (C++) code that starts and stops a timer.  So what are you timing exactly, or more succinctly, what are you throwing into the mix that has nothing to do with the computations?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not sure what you mean in #1. I'm creating a variable, its name is `asum` its type is `long long` and it's value is `a[bsize]`. I will add the rest of my timing code to the qustion.

Comment: You should also run the tests unrolling the loop and with instructions to parallelize the operation.  Declare the arrays as constant, which should help the compiler optimize better.

Comment: ok, so is `bsize` within bounds of the `a` array?  We really need a [mcve].  Anything that can go wrong that you may not have noticed could impact your results.

Comment: @huddie96:  arrays must have a fixed size capacity defined by a compile-time constant.  Otherwise use a dynamic array (e.g.`new`), `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think i do use `new`, can you show me where your speaking of?

Comment: @huddie96 -- So you're timing `cout` statements also?  You should be timing just the "raw" computation code, not output statements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's a great point. I didn't think of that at all. I'll fix that.

Comment: A variable length array example:  `int b = 25; int a[b];`.  Using `new` :  `int * c = new int[36];`  Vector: `std::vector<int> v;`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews don't I use that? I'm a bit confused as to where I am not doing that.

Comment: BTW, if `bsize` is the capacity of your array, then `a[bsize]` is undefined access (your accessing past the end of the array).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the driver to not time the `cout`, no time change. @ThomasMatthewsm bsize is the size of array `b`. Array `a` is size `bsize+1`

Comment: As has been said, it's clearly a pipelining issue - you have a data dependency in your loop body, that is also carried forward through the next iteration. In the first example instead the loop body can go fully in parallel.

Comment: @Peter or Matteo, do one of you want to submit an answer so I can accept it. Makes sense that it's pipelining. Probably never would have thought of that myself tbh, smart answer.

Comment: @huddie96 I'll pass, as I don't know enough about recent architectures to write a good quality answer, and am currently on my phone, sorry. I won't take any offense if anyone wants to write an answer inspired by a comment of mine.

Comment: exactly! https://onlinegdb.com/hzta8aQfl

Comment: we have not used any parallel processing thing here, Full Adder needs 2 XOR gates, 2 AND gates, and 1 OR gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the questions comments by Peter and Matteo.

Although XOR would be equal/faster for a single operation vs addition. The XOR version is slower than the summation version because of [pipelining](https:////en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining).

One XOR must wait for the previous XOR operation to finish before it can start its operation whereas the summation (addition) can run in parallel and therefore make use of pipelining. In turn, allowing summation to end up faster than the bitwise XOR.

This answer is inspired by Peters comment. I just wanted to make sure the question had an available answer and Peter opted not to write one.

Edit:

Thanks to phuclv, altering the code to sum array `a` and `b` individually (see comment below) breaks the dependency and results in the XOR returning quicker/equal than Summation.

Comment: if it's really because of the dependency then break the dependency by `{ sumA ^= a[i]; sumB ^= b[i]; } return sumA ^ sumB;`